# tool or vbscript to delete first x lines from multiple files?

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I've fiddled a bit with wingrep but doesn't seem to support this.

Has anyone had any luck with say deleting the first 7 lines of text from all .txt files in directory "C:\my_direc\"?

I'm using Win XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a VBScript solution. Haven't tested it, but it should at least put you on the right track.

```
Dim FSO, txs, fld, fil, content, nLinesToSkip, i
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

nLinesToSkip = 7

fld = FSO.GetFolder("C:\test\")
For Each fil In fld
    If Right(fil.Name, 3) = "txt" Then

        Set txs = fil.OpenAsTextStream(1) ' 1 = for reading
        For i = 1 To nLinesToSkip
            txs.SkipLine
        Next i
        content = txs.ReadAll
        txs.Close

        Set txs = fil.OpenAsTextStream(2) ' 2 = for writing
        txs.Write content
        txs.Close

    End If
Next fil
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Delete Lines](http://www.ab-tools.com/en/software/deletelines/) tool